# 3D surface code and unionfind

Tags: error-correction, surface-code

I was reading some papers about the UnionFind Decoder but I don't get how matching can be used to decode on a 3D surface code. If I understood correctly every layer in our 3D surface code corresponds to a different syndrome measurement at different time steps. My question is, if I apply the UnionFind decoder and I find a matching between levels how do I interpret this? Is there even a correction to apply between layers?